# Deployment of Wave Analytics components failing

Tags: deployment, query, json, dashboard, einstein-analytics

I have retrieved the wave analytics components using workbench without any issues from source org.But while deploying in the target org is giving an error :

> "  Error: Unrecognized field "query" (Class
>   sfdc.insights.connect.api.input.dashboard.step.AggregateFlexQueryStepInputRepresentation),
>   not marked as ignorable  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
>   (through reference chain:
>   sfdc.insights.connect.api.input.DashboardStateInputRepresentation["steps"]->sfdc.insights.connect.api.input.dashboard.step.AggregateFlexQueryStepInputRepresentation["query"])
>   "

Please help me in understanding this error and steps to fix it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, it appears as though you've retrieved a Wave Dashboard Component that's using the Connect API to run an AggregrateResults Query of some kind. I believe "query" refers to the metadata containing the actual querystring which will be connected to some kind of endpoint or database that your target org most likely isn't connected to or will have a different reference to. You need to "unbind" the reference that's been created in the source org and recreate it so that it's linked to datasources as referenced from your target org.